# Extract element having highest attribute value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below object, which can have many **careerLevels** (I have shown 2 for now):

```
    var input =
       {

       "careerLevel": "Associate",
       "careerLevels": [
           {
               "201609": 21,
               "201610": 22,
               "201611": 23,
               "careerID": "10000120"
           },
           {
               "201609": 31,
               "201610": 32,
               "201611": 33,
               "careerID": "10000130"
           }]
   };
```

I want to check **careerID** attribute and i need to extract that element which has highest **careerID** value.
So in this case the output will look like :

```
var output=  {"201609": 31,
               "201610": 32,
               "201611": 33}
```

What i have tried is as below :

```
var res = Math.max.apply(Math, oldArr.careerLevels.map(function (o) { return o.careerID; })) // This gives me the highest careerID value

var highestOrderArr = oldArr.careerLevels.filter(element => { 
                // i think here i need to make a check for the comparison
});
```

Comment: Did you even try to do it?

Comment: Let me add what iam trying.

Comment: The objective here is not to ask us to write code for you but to help you fix code you write that isn't working as expected. Using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) could be helpful here

Comment: This question contains no JSON and has nothing to do with JSON. JavaScript object literals are not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use reduce, to get the highest `careerID` and output that object.

```js
var input ={
   "careerLevel": "Associate",
   "careerLevels": [
       {
           "201609": 21,
           "201610": 22,
           "201611": 23,
           "careerID": "10000120"
       },
       {
           "201609": 31,
           "201610": 32,
           "201611": 33,
           "careerID": "10000130"
       }]
};
   
const out = input.careerLevels.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return (prev.careerID > current.careerID) ? prev : current
}, false)

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is sorting and getting the last object.

```js
var input = {  "careerLevel": "Associate",  "careerLevels": [{      "201609": 21,      "201610": 22,      "201611": 23,      "careerID": "10000120"    },    {      "201609": 31,      "201610": 32,      "201611": 33,      "careerID": "10000130"    }  ]},
    highest = input.careerLevels.sort((a, b) => a.careerID - b.careerID).pop();

console.log(highest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using the function `reduce`

```js
var input = {  "careerLevel": "Associate",  "careerLevels": [{      "201609": 21,      "201610": 22,      "201611": 23,      "careerID": "10000120"    },    {      "201609": 31,      "201610": 32,      "201611": 33,      "careerID": "10000130"    }  ]},
    highest = input.careerLevels.reduce((a, c) => c.careerID > a.careerID ? c : a, {careerID: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER});

console.log(highest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But in my case, the element with highest careerId not necessarily be the last one.

Comment: @user3205921 look carefully.  I'm sorting the array and then getting the last one.